# Snake Game - why does the snake skip a tile?

Tags: c++, sfml

I've made a Snake Game, and it works nicely, however, when the snake gets to the edge of the screen, I made it loop back around.
The problem is that when he loops back around, it seems to skip a piece?

I don't know how to say this so here's a video of it.
https://youtu.be/fxuEYsrIZMU

Instead of just appearing on the edge, it skips 1 to 2 tiles.
Here is the code snippet:

```
void update(std::vector<sf::RectangleShape>& food) {
        std::cout << body.size();
        for(int i = body.size() - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            checkBounds(body.at(i)); // Check Snake is in screen.
            /* ... */
        }
        checkBounds(body.at(0));
        /* ... */
    }
void checkBounds(sf::RectangleShape& point) {
        if(point.getPosition().x < 0) point.move(WIDTH, 0);
        if(point.getPosition().y < 0) point.move(0, HEIGHT);
        if(point.getPosition().x > WIDTH) point.move(-WIDTH, 0);
        if(point.getPosition().y > HEIGHT) point.move(0, -HEIGHT);
    }
```

WIDTH, HEIGHT is the screen W. and H.
body is a `std::vector<sf::RectangleShape>`
Here is the full code:
https://pastebin.com/sr4Tbrin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you have a board of grid size 10

When you decide to wrap, the snake's head will be at 11

But he will be moved to 11-10 = 1, not 0.

You need:

```
    if(point.getPosition().x > WIDTH) point.move(-(WIDTH+1), 0);
    if(point.getPosition().y > HEIGHT) point.move(0, -(HEIGHT+1));
```

Comment: The problem is in these lines indeed, but the solution is incorrect: the correct values are -(WIDTH + 1) and -(HEIGHT + 1) respectively. The values you've provided would cause the snake to skip one piece more, i.e. it will end up on the 2nd field.

Comment: No problem. As for the downvote, I think it's going to be more visible if you ask this question as a comment to your main question, not to the answer.

Comment: @KjMag Thanks! Fixed